# Pandoc grid_table columns not aligning correctly

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to export markdown files to PDF. I'm using OS X Yosemite.

When markdown is exported to pdf (via pandoc) the content of the table columns overlay the content in the next column.

Is there a pandoc command to set the column width? Or, perhaps, a command to standardise column width?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219629/how-to-control-cell-width-in-pandoc-markdown-table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents of your table cells are wide enough to need wrapping, then you need to use pandoc "multiline tables" or "grid tables," not simple or pipe tables.  The relative widths will be calculated automatically from the relative widths in the source file, [as described in pandoc's User's Guide](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables).  You can also set the overall source width using `--columns`.

Comment: Thank you, yes now using "multiline tables": much better. Thanks John.