# How to create this boxes in markdown

Tags: markdown

[Reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clh6T.png)

I want to write text inside the boxes as in the  provided picture (from the  Typora markdown reference). How  can I achieve this behaviour? I know how to  obtain boxes as

```
Text
```

but  can't figure out how to obtain the boxes as presented in the picture.

Comment: You might find answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25654845/10132227

Comment: @c-anirudh I  already examined this post